# Determinant of a particular large matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I've been trying to solve this problem but I stucked. 
Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ with size $ 2011 \times 2011$ , and given the condition below

\begin{equation}a_{ij}=   \begin{cases}
      (-1)^{|i-j|}, & \text{if}\ i \neq j \\
      2, & \text{if} \ i = j
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Find $\det(A)$. I was thinking to either form block matrices or do row operation, but it became a mess. Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** We can write $A$ as $$A = I_{2011} + {\bf x} {\bf x}^\top ,$$ where ${\bf x} = (1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots, -1, 1)^\top$. Now apply the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I have found that I could do row operations and will leave 1's on the diagonal entries (1st to 2010-th) except the 2011-th entry. (the last diagonal yield "2012"). So, the determinant is just the product of diagonal entries = $1 \overbrace{\times 1 \times 1 \times \cdot \times 1}^{2010 times} \times 2012 = 2012$

Comment: Yours is quite a nice argument, too!

Comment: (And you're welcome.)